# pass a list to cython function and return a list

Tags: python, cython

I am new to cython and I am googling for hours.
I want to pass a list of e.g. integers to a cython function, do some calculation and return a the list.

something like this:

```
cimport libc.stdlib as lib 

def do_calc(list_a):
    cdef size_t n = len(list_a)
    cdef int* data = <int*>lib.malloc(n * sizeof(int))
    cdef int i 

    for i in range(n):
        data[i] = 2 * list_a[i]

    return data
```

I am not going to pass numpy array as arguments.

Finally call the function like:

```
import example_cy
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(example_cy.do_calc(a))
```

error:

```
example_cy.pyx:11:11: Cannot convert 'int *' to Python object
```

Thanks in advance for any guide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "Cannot convert <type\_name>\* to Python object" in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763480/error-message-cannot-convert-type-name-to-python-object-in-cython)

Comment: The duplicate explains what why your code doesn't work. You either can use the receipt from the duplicate or start with creating a list in the first place.

Comment: @ead The suggested answer works but after I saw the asnswer of Andrey and read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slight modified example:

```
cimport libc.stdlib as lib 

def do_calc(list_a):
    cdef size_t n = len(list_a)
    # `data` declaration changed from `int* data`
    cdef int *data = <int *> lib.malloc(n * sizeof(int))
    cdef int i
    try:
        for i in range(n):
            data[i] = 2 * list_a[i]
        # pack C values back to python int objects
        return [x for x in data[:n]]
    finally:
        # don't forget to fee allocated memory
        lib.free(data)
```

You can read more explanation in the official docs: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html