# Is there a way to call a cdef class method that has non-pythonic arguments?

Tags: cython

Effectively, I am cleaning up a cython module that has many globally scoped functions and variables. I thought cdef classes would be a great way to package some of these functions. But I ran into an issue when trying to call some of the methods of these classes. I boilded it down to these two examples that show my issue. The functionality of the code is unimportant, I am just trying to demonstrate the problem I am facing.

```
cdef class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    cdef int deref(self, int *bar):
        return bar[0]

cdef int bar = 5
foo = Foo()
foo.deref(&bar)
```

If I run this code I get an error

> Cannot convert 'int *' to Python object

But If I define everything in global scope it works just fine:

```
cdef int deref(int *bar):
    return bar[0]
cdef int bar = 5
deref(&bar)
```

My question is: Is it possible to call a cdef method in this mannor?

My thought was that it would work since it is all being done within cython, but for some reason cython wants to convert the pointer into a python object and then back into a cython object? Is this always the case? I thought cdef classes were an effective tool to use when using cython.

Anyways, I have exhausted my attempts at solving this issue myself and wanted to ask here before abandoning cdef classes and going back to functional programming.

Comment: There is no `foo`. If you use `Foo`, it should be `Foo().deref(&bar)` and it works.

Comment: You are right, I edited the code to add a `foo = Foo()`

I see the problem, I need to define foo like:

`cdef Foo foo = Foo()`

Otherwise it is a python object.

If you answer in a post I will :check: it :) @ead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally Cython would detect the `cdef` type of a variable, e.g. for

```py
def doit():
    cdef int bar = 5
    foo = Foo()
    return foo.deref(&bar)
```

Cython would see, that `foo` is of type `cdef Foo` and treat it as such (the above code builds).

Not so for the global variables:

```
foo = Foo()
```

this is implicitly a `def` variable, which can be accessed (or set) via `modulename.foo`. That means, Cython cannot be sure, that `foo` is of type `Foo` - it could be set to `int`, `float` and what not.

Thus Cython must assume that `foo` is a pure Python-object with a (`def`-) method called `deref` which has Python arguments, and a pointer [cannot be cast to a Python object automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53763480/5769463) - which leads to the error you are observing.

Declaring `foo` as

```
cdef Foo foo=Foo()
```

hides the variable from pure-python, so it is no longer possible to access it via `modulename.foo` and to assign some arbitrary object to it. Thus it possible for Cython to assume, that `foo` is really of type `Foo`, thus granting access to `cdef`-functions of the class `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

foo must be declared a Foo object

```
cdef Foo foo = Foo()
```

Then all is well